# Unsecured traffic between two ec2 instances within the same vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

Is it save to transfer unsecured http messages between two ec2 instances within the same vpc in aws?

Or is it necessary to use ssh tunneling etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's safe in the sense that only your instances exist in the VPC. So the traffic between your two instances in your VPC cannot be sniffed by a 3rd party.

> Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (Amazon VPC) lets you provision a
>   logically isolated section of the Amazon Web Services (AWS) Cloud
>   where you can launch AWS resources in a virtual network that you
>   define. You have complete control over your virtual networking
>   environment, including selection of your own IP address range,
>   creation of subnets, and configuration of route tables and network
>   gateways.

Source: [Amazon VPC](https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/)